$LL=\left \{ xyzy^R : xyz\in L \right \}$ is context free language
Let $L$ be a regular language over $\Sigma = \left \{ 0,1 \right \}$.
Define $LL=\left \{ xyzy^R : xyz\in L \right \}$ where $x,y,z\in \Sigma^*$. The question asked to show that $LL$ is context free language.
Some context
$L$ is regular, thus $L=L(A) : A=\left \{ \Sigma,Q,q_0,\left \{ q_f \right \} ,\delta\right \}$
(I'm assuming w.l.o.g that $A$ has a single accepting state)
For each $p,q\in Q$, let $A_{p,q}$ be the automaton $A$, except that initial state is $p$ and final state is $q$.
Let $L'=\left \{ xyzy^R : xyz\in \Sigma^* \right \}$
$L'$ is context free language and the following grammar will testify for that:
$S\to S_1|S_2$
$S_1\to DS_1D|\varepsilon$
$D\to 0|1$
$S_2\to 0S_20|1S_21|S_1$
Let $L''=\left \{ w\in L : w=xyz \ s.t\ x,y,z\in \Sigma^* \right \}$
From the closer porpitas of regular languages, $L''$ is regular because $L''=\bigcup_{q,p \in Q}\left [ L(A_{q_0,q})\cdot L(A_{q,p})\cdot L(A_{p,q_f}) \right ]$
Let $L'''=L''\cdot\Sigma^*$
From the closer of regular languages to concatenation, $L'''$ is regular.
Finally, from the closer of intersection of context free languages and regular languages we get that $LL=L'\cap L'''$ is context free.
Where I got stuck
Does the intersection of $L'=\left \{ xyzy^R : xyz\in \Sigma^* \right \}$ with $L'''=\left \{ w\in L : w=xyz \ s.t\ x,y,z\in \Sigma^* \right \}\cdot  \Sigma^*$ gives $LL=\left \{ xyzy^R : xyz\in L \right \}$ ?

We discourage "Please check whether my attempted solution is correct" questions, as the answer is unlikely to help future readers.

@D.W. You wrote me once that I need to show effort and not to ask "please answer my question", as mention here https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/how-do-i-ask-a-good-homework-question Well, this is the effort. I also don't want to be arrogant and say this is correct because I truly don't sure.

That is true too.  I realize it might be counter-intuitive. We are looking for posts that will contribute to building knowledge on the Internet and be useful to others.  "Here is an exercise, what is the solution?" probably doesn't contribute much to that, and "Here is an exercise, here is my attempted solution, is it correct?" probably doesn't contribute much to that either.  If you notice, the advice on that page isn't solely (or even primarily) about "effort"; some suggestions are to make the question useful to others, ask about concepts, ask about a specific aspect of the problem, etc.

I think now that @D.W. has a point although I answered some questions of this nature in the past, and when I did I tried to write an answer that would be helpful in some way to future readers. Anyway, I think it would be better to point where you got stuck, and why you think your solution is wrong instead of asking us to verify it.  This way, you might end up proving the claim yourself. If you managed to come up with a correct solution on your own, then you will probably be able to check it, unless it contains a part you do not understand, then you can make a specific question about that part.

@BaderAbuRadi I tried to edit it to more specific part.

@D.W. Does the edit I made make the question more suitable?

Can you credit the source of the question? I liked the last two questions that are similar to this that you asked, and I wonder where you got them from. Also, I have not read the details of the question yet, but it looks like your question appears only in the last two lines. Right? If this is the case, then I think it is better to extract the question from the bigger context. Can you? Anyway, I still need to read the details.

@BaderAbuRadi This are question from computation models exams I worked on.
You are absolutely right that my question appears in the last two lines, but I think one will need the context above in order to see where it came from (yet you can still examine the claims I made without the proofs)

The answer you give has some good ideas, but the parts do not fit into a solution to the question.
First the problem. The languages $L'$ and $L''$ both do use the variables (substrings) $x,y,z$ but those are not visible in the language itself. Thus when intersecting the components $L'$ and $L'''$ nothing will force that the substrings indicated by $x,y,z$ match in both languages.
In fact, when you look closely you will see that $L′=\{xyzy^R:xyz∈Σ^*\} = \Sigma^*$. (We can take $y=z=\varepsilon$.) Also it makes no sense in observing that $L''$ is regular using closure properties, as $L'' = L$, which is the regular language we started with.
But, like I said, it has a good basic idea. One only needs to mark the different parts of the strings. These markings can be deleted using a homomorphism afterwards.
Thus, instead, consider $L′=\{ x{\cdot}1{\cdot}y{\cdot}2{\cdot}z{\cdot}3{\cdot}y^R:x,y,z∈Σ^*\}$ as a context-free language, where $1,2,3$ are abstract symbols.
Likewise define the language $L'' = \{x{\cdot}1{\cdot}y{\cdot}2{\cdot}z : xyz \in L \}$.
Now your construction can be made to work.
